# the method document of the iwebbrowser2 object failed

Tags: vba, syntax-error

When I launch the site via my code, there is an error of type "method document of object iwebbrowser2 failed " at the level of my variable "oDoc"

```
Private Function CreerNavigateur(ByVal mails As String)
Dim IE As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim Htable, maTable As Object
Dim text As String
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "https://csrtool-ssl.sso.infra.ftgroup/csrtool_web/Bricks/pg/osuit/pages/identity/IdentityAccountAndUsers?type=emailAlias&value=" & mails & "&tab_main=AccountInfo"
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    Set oDoc = IE.Document
    Set Htable = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
   ' MsgBox Htable.innerhtml
    Set maTable = Htable.getElementsByTagName("span")
    'MsgBox maTable(0).href
    'myData = maTable(0).innertext
    'MsgBox (myData)
    IE.Quit
    'On libère les variables
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
End Function
```

thank you for helping me to see my mistake

Comment: Try Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")  and also debug "https://csrtool-ssl.sso.infra.ftgroup/csrtool_web/Bricks/pg/osuit/pages/identity/IdentityAccountAndUsers?type=emailAlias&value=" & mails & "&tab_main=AccountInfo"  to verfify is expected value.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093430/busy-method-of-iuwebbrowser2-object-failed

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons of such errors are security restricitions. Try to add `infra.ftgroup` to Trusted sites zone in IE settings:

[image: internet properties]

[image: trusted sites]

Also try to open the website in compatibility view:

[image: compatibility view]

[image: compatibility view settings]

And play a bit with modes on Developer tools <kbd>F12</kbd> - Emulation tab:

[image: ie modes]