# 'Busy' method of 'IUWebBrowser2' object failed

Tags: vba, web, web-scraping

When I launch the site via my code, there is an error of type "method document of object iwebbrowser2 failed " at the level of my variable "oDoc"

```
Private Function CreerNavigateur(ByVal mails As String)
Dim IE As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim Htable, maTable As Object
Dim text As String
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate "https://csrtool-ssl.sso.infra.ftgroup/csrtool_web/Bricks/pg/osuit/pages/identity/IdentityAccountAndUsers?type=emailAlias&value=" & mails & "&tab_main=AccountInfo"
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    Set oDoc = IE.Document
    Set Htable = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
   ' MsgBox Htable.innerhtml
    Set maTable = Htable.getElementsByTagName("span")
    'MsgBox maTable(0).href
    'myData = maTable(0).innertext
    'MsgBox (myData)
    IE.Quit
    'On libère les variables
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
End Function
```

thank you for helping me to see my mistake

Comment: Try using maximized ie window `Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`

Comment: add "Microsoft internet controls" from Tools=> References then try executing macro

Comment: is that working fine without error? your problem solved?

Comment: it worked but I see this error "runtime error -2147467259 ': unspecified automation error"
on the line "While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend"

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions under different accounts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57091574/the-method-document-of-the-iwebbrowser2-object-failed#comment100708048_57091574

Comment: @QHarr I did not understand your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formalizing my answer try maximized ie window and updated code will be

```
Private Function CreerNavigateur(ByVal mails As String)
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim Htable, maTable As Object
    Dim text As String

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate "https://csrtool-ssl.sso.infra.ftgroup/csrtool_web/Bricks/pg/osuit/pages/identity/IdentityAccountAndUsers?type=emailAlias&value=" & mails & "&tab_main=AccountInfo"

    While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

    Set oDoc = ie.Document
    Set Htable = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)
    'MsgBox Htable.innerhtml
    Set maTable = Htable.getElementsByTagName("span")
    'MsgBox maTable(0).href
    'myData = maTable(0).innertext
    'MsgBox (myData)
    ie.Quit
    'On libère les variables
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I see this error "runtime error -2147467259 ': unspecified automation error" on the line "While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend"

Comment: please try above mentioned code here we used ie not IE

Comment: same mistake "run-time error '-2147467259': unspecified automation error"

Comment: i have not answer of my question

Comment: @ArmelKounou  set visible property as true and see webpage opens or not if no then check compatibility view

Comment: @QHarr even i faced the same problem, if i use ShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED then we can use win API here its not required

Comment: @arunv the page opens but there is an error "automation error
unspecified error"

Comment: the solution to my question is: Set ie = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")