# How do I get around breaking InternetExplorer Object with Application.SendKeys

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, sendkeys

[image]

I thought I was well on my way to success. What I'm attempting to do is Load a URL in IE, input some data, then run a report.

To accomplish this, I've created an InternetExplorer object, used that object to turn on visibility, and navigate to my URL.

Upon getting to the page, I have to supply some data to let the report generator do what it needs to do, then press enter. Once I'm to this point I need to do some navigation to different URLs until I arrive at the report page. To accomplish this, I'm attempting to return to using my InternetExplore object (IE) to navigate, but any time I use IE.*anything* the 462 error pops.

My question is two fold:

1. The object was good to begin with, I have to assume it was the use of Application.Send or Application.Wait that has somehow broke my object, why?
2. What did I do wrong?
3. Suggestions on how to resolve this?

   ```
   Dim text As String
   Dim IE
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   '
   IE.Visible = True
   IE.Navigate "http://~~~~~~~~~.net/reports/views/result/reportResult.faces"
   '
   text = "somedata"
   .
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
       Application.SendKeys (text), True
   '
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
       Application.SendKeys vbCrLf, True
   '   
   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
       IE.Navigate "http://~~~~~~~~~.net/reports/views/myMrs/myFavorites.faces"
   ```

Comment: Is the URL accessible via internet or in intranet? Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57094762/2165759).

Comment: Your structure of your program is wrong. See all these posts https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Do%20Until%20IE.readyState%20%3d%204

Comment: you would be better off getting the elements of the page and using those to invoke click events and such instead of SendKeys.  A lot can go wrong with SendKeys.

Comment: @Sorceri - Thanks for the suggestion. I've never done this before (interacting with a web site with a macro), so it was a challenge for me to find all the syntax correct. I'll post the final solution here in a bit after i clean it up, but it is working perfectly. 
Mark and omegastripes thanks for your input. The url is internal to the corp network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end product was completely different than where I was headed. Thanks to those who provided input, especially Sorceri who turned me on to focusing on the elements.

Below is the finished code segment (I have more things I do after this but this gets me where I needed to go).

```
Private Sub OpenReport()
Dim text As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim IE
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
text = "somecode"

'Load link
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://~~~~~~~~~/reports/views/result/reportResult.faces"

'Wait for page to load
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'fill in the pcode
IE.Document.getelementbyid("code").Value = text

'Click Submit
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block")(0).Click

'Wait for page to load
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'Click on Favorites
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("myMRSFavoritesLink")(0).Click

'Wait for page to load
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'Click on report
IE.Document.getElementsByName("myFavoritesForm:treeTable_tableId:1:infoButton101644806j_id__v_19")(0).Click

'Wait for page to load
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Click on execute report
IE.Document.getElementsByName("setParametersForm:startReportButton")(0).Click

End Sub
```